# How to do error handling when fetching data in angularjs service

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

This code fetches categories and give them to controller.

```
sampleApp.factory('SCService', function($http, $q) {

    var SuperCategories = [];
    var SCService =  {};

    SCService.GetSuperCategories = function() {
        var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: SuperCategoryURL,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
            data: "action=GET"
        };
        if ( SuperCategories.length == 0 ) {
            return $http(req).then(function (response) {
                SuperCategories = response.data;
                return SuperCategories;
            });
        }else {
            return $q.when(SuperCategories);
        }
    }

    return SCService;
});
```

I think code is perfect until there is no error in http request.

My query is how to do error handling (try catch or something like that), in case if server have some issue or may be cgi-script have some issue and not able to server the request.

Answer (score 1):

Angular promises use a method `catch` for that.

```
return $http(req).then(function (response) {
    SuperCategories = response.data;
    return SuperCategories;
}).catch(function(error) {
    // Do what you want here
});
```

You should use also `finally` :

```
return $http(req).then(function (response) {
    SuperCategories = response.data;
    return SuperCategories;
}).catch(function(error) {
    // Do what you want here
}).finally(function() {
    // Always executed. Clean up variables, call a callback, etc...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just wanted to understand which is good option? Using try catch or success/error call backs?

Comment: Keep in mind that a "classic" `try {} cath(...) {}` will have a different behavior with the `$exceptionHandler`. Read this article : https://medium.com/@bluepnume/sane-scalable-angular-apps-are-tricky-but-not-impossible-lessons-learned-from-paypal-checkout-c5320558d4ef

Answer (score 1):

Write like

```
 return $http(req).then(function (response) {
               //success callback
            },
 function(){
//Failure callback
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use callback methods from controller Like

Controller.js

```
service.GetSuperCategories(function (data) {console.log('success'},function (error){console.log('error'});
```

service.js

```
sampleApp.factory('SCService', function($http, $q) {

    var SuperCategories = [];
    var SCService =  {};

    SCService.GetSuperCategories = function(successMethod,errorMethod) {
        var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: SuperCategoryURL,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
            data: "action=GET"
        };
        return $http(req).then(successMethod(data),
errorMethod(error));
    }

    return SCService;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .success and .error methods of $http service, as below

```
$http(req).success(function(data, status, headers){
    // success callback:  Enters if status = 200
}).error(function(status, headers){
    // error callback: enters otherwise
});
```